# How many assists did Maradona provide for his national team?

Tags: football

I've read many soccer statistics and I'm almost sure there is no current figure of how many assists Maradona provided while playing for Argentina. But all of Maradona's games are recorded and it's possible to get those stats. Has anyone calculated Maradona's assists for Argentina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, they seem to be available. They are being compiled on [the Spanish version of Wikipedia.](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Maradona#2)

> Club assists: 208
>
> National team assists (including u-20 assists) 33+22 = 55.
>
> Total senior assists: 241
>
> Total assists including U-20: 263

Answer (score 4):

"Assists" in football are a (relatively) modern statistic and weren't collected in Maradona's playing days. Unless anyone has been through recordings of every international match Maradona played (assuming that video exists of them all, which is by no means guaranteed), this statistic isn't going to be available.

Comment: yes, video exists of all of them, that's why I said it could be made. Many statistics that later were incorporated by federations were started by common people. FIFA has published stats like that in his website, also CONMEBOL, etc. it doesnt have to be made by an official entity as long as it is correctly made, same for goals

Answer (score 0):

I'd also encourage you to explore Maradona's [Transfermarkt profile](https://www.transfermarkt.com/diego-maradona/nationalmannschaft/spieler/8024). The values appear different than the current accepted answer. I personally trust the fidelity of Transfermarkt statistics and enjoy exploring the various statistics disaggregations and details for the respective games played.

Comment: As far as I see, there are no statistics for the national team, that is what the question was about. Only assists in competitions for clubs

Comment: There _are_ indeed statistics for the national team, the right pane provides details. I can provide a more appropriate link.

Comment: transfermarkt count being fouled for a scored penalty as an assist, so I'd take their numbers with a pinch of salt.